# when do I need to have a floating/non-floating input at a SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, safety, grounding

I am studying reference designs for my PSU, and they all have a floating earth connection (or have no earth connection). When I inspect industrial power supplies, some have earth connection, some have only L/N inputs. How do you decide when one must have an earth connection or not.

Secondly, how do I convert a non-floating AC PSU input to floating type? E.g., on the below circuit

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to clear up what's happening in the schematic you show.

Zoom in on the schematic, and you will see that the ground on the left side of the transformer is labeled "Vpri", and on the right side "GND".  Vpri isn't tied to any particular ground at all.  It's shown with a ground symbol only because it is used as the reference for all other voltages on the primary side of the transformer.

Since Vpri is tied to the negative side of the full wave bridge rectifying the incoming AC, it will be at the negative peak voltage of the AC part of the time.  This is relative to something outside this circuit.  That would be a dangerous voltage for a user to touch.  However, it doesn't matter since nothing on the primary side of the transformer is accessible other than the wall plug.  Everything else stays internal to the case of the supply, so it can be at dangerous voltages without harm.

The ground of the secondary side is meant to be connected to externally.  However, this is isolated from the line voltages on the primary side by the insulation in the tranformer.

That's a valid and safe way of isolating the user from the dangerous voltages on the primary side.  Such devices would need to pass something known as a "Hi-pot" test during manufacturing.  The tie the two AC inputs together, and deliberately apply several times the expect max voltage between there and the output GND.  There may only be some very minimum leakage to pass, usually in the micro-Amp range.  Hi-pot test voltages are usually in the 1.5 to 2.5 kV range, depending on which standard is being complied with.

The point is that you're safe touching GND even when TP1 and TP4 have maximum line voltage on them, plus some voltage spikes.

There is no need to "convert" this circuit from non-floating to floating, because it already is floating.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Am I correct that I can't use an insulator meter to do hi-pot test, and it requires a different measurement device?

Comment: I refer this insulation meter that can apply 2.5kV [link](http://se.farnell.com/tenma/72-9405/tester-insulation-resistance/dp/2064097#)

Comment: @Johan: I don't know what a "insulator meter" is, but for hi-pot test you need a high impedance high voltage source in series with a current meter.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit is not a nice example as it uses the same symbol for input (primary) ground and output ground. Only when you zoom in do you see that it has 2 grounds.

You talk about *floating* which would suggest that the primary ground is "floating" but it is not really floating, it is mains connected and unsafe to touch.

Look at the designs with a mains earth input, it will basically be the same circuit where the output ground is often connected to the mains earth.

What to choose depends on the user case. If a mains earth is expected to be present then it would be a good idea to use it.

The "floating" ground supplies will often have their output floating at around half the mains voltage because there is no ground reference. This might or might not be a problem depending on the usage. Series resistance is high, there is only the Y-rated capacitor between the mains side and ground. This capacitor should not be so large that the user will feel a "tingle".

Answer (score 0):

The primary side of that transformer isn't floating, because you still have a galvanic connection to the supply. If you wanted it floating, you'd put another transformer in front, but there is no point in doing so.

The secondary side is floating unless you connect GND to PE.

Whether you need a ground connection depends largely on the [Appliance Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes).